# using the city-state gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys im currently working on a devise sign up form, the end goal is  a user can select a state from the united states and a select tag below will populate with the correct cities in that state. im using the city-state gem. https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

ive looked at other examples like this one https://forum.upcase.com/t/dependent-country-city-state/7038 my code is below

**routes.rb**

```
resources :states, only: :new
```

**registrations.new.html.erb**

```
   <div class="field">
        <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(CS.states(:us)), {:prompt => "State"}, {:class => "signup-input-container--input", :id => "state-picker"} %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
        <%= f.select :city, options_for_select([]),{}, {:class => "signup-input-container--input", :id => "city-picker"} %>
   </div>
```

**main.js**

```
 document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  var state = document.getElementById("state-picker");
  state.addEventListener("change", function() {
    Rails.ajax({
     url: "/states?country=" + "United States" + "&state=" + 
     state.value,
     type: "GET"
    })
  })
});
```

**registrations-controller.erb**

```
 def new
  super
  @cities = CS.get(:us, params[:state])
 end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
    var city = document.getElementById("city-picker");

    while (city.firstChild) city.removeChild(city.firstChild);

    var placeholder = document.createElement("option");
    placeholder.text = "Choose a city";
    placeholder.value = "";
    city.appendChild(placeholder);

   <% @cities.each do |c| %>
     city.options[city.options.length] = new Option('<%= c %>');
   <% end %>
```

im trying to get this to work the way the example link shows. the only difference is that users will only choose states from the US and citys

Comment: What's going wrong then? You've described what you've done, but not what isn't working. Are you finding JavaScript errors? Server side errors? Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @philnash I get no errors, when i select a state from the dropdown nothing populates in the cities select tag

Comment: Does your JavaScript `change` event fire at all?

Comment: yes it fires and shoots this in the console "GET http://localhost:3000/states?country=UnitedStates&state=Arizona 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Ah, ok so we have a 404. What does `rails routes` say about where your endpoint to request states is? I see you're including it as part of the `new` action in the registrations controller? Is that the best place?

Comment: i ran rails routes and this what i got  "new_state GET    /states/new(.:format)                                                                    states#new"

Comment: i need to collect this info when a user is signing up thats why i have it in the registrations controller new action

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in the comments the issue appears to be that you are requesting the wrong URL for your cities.

You have a route at `/states/new` but are making the request to `/states`. Try updating your `main.js` to:

```
 document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  var state = document.getElementById("state-picker");
  state.addEventListener("change", function() {
    Rails.ajax({
     url: "/states/new?state=" + state.value,
     type: "GET"
    })
  })
});
```

(I removed the country parameter in the URL because you don't seem to be using it, you say you only need this for the US anyway.)

Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: I am still getting a 404 error, i think this is happening because of routes, i am very confused

Comment: What happens if you make a request directly to `/states/new?state=CA` (for example)?

Comment: ahhhh i got "uninitialized constant StatesController" i think my problem is trying to use this in the devise registrations controller

Comment: Right, this goes back to my question earlier about why you have this in the registrations controller. It may be that you need this data for registration, however it would make more sense to just call to a standalone `StatesController` to get the list of states. I'd create a `StatesController` and move the action and the `.js.erb` view into it. I'd probably also use the `index` action rather than new too.

Comment: i think im getting closer, i added  get 'states/', to: 'families/registrations#new' to my routes im now getting a 500 error

Comment: Woo hoo! What was it?

Comment: devise_scope :user do
      get 'states', to: 'users/registrations#city'
   end

Comment: Glad you're all sorted!

Comment: spoke to soon ! i got a successful request and im getting the right parameters but i am not recieving anything when this runs in my method CS.get(:us,params[state])

Comment: You might need to ensure that you're passing the state as a symbol. Try `CS.get(:us, params[:state].downcase.to_sym)`

Comment: i was hoping this would work but i got this error undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Oh, so you're not receiving anything in the `params`? What do you get if you log the `params` object? What is the full URL that your JavaScript is requesting here?

Comment: i logged params.inspect and got "<ActionController::Parameters {"state"=>"Colorado", "controller"=>"families/registrations", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false> "

Comment: In your comment above you wrote `CS.get(:us,params[state])`. `state` here is just `nil` so you are calling `params[nil]` which is also returning `nil`. Make sure you have a symbol or string in `CS.get(:us, params["state"])`.

Comment: i had a symbol  that was just a typo above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186334/discussion-between-philnash-and-kevin-lopez).